# Selecting dashboard technology - extjs, flex, angularjs etc

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache-flex, extjs

To give a brief background I am a C++ programmer who has worked mainly on back-end systems, but now has to develop a front-end gui (mainly an interactive  dashboard with lots of charts and comparisons and so on) as well along with a back-end financial system.

Few years back I had worked on a similar project and used Flex to develop a dashboard. But searching the net, it seems that Flex is not well supported anymore (nobody pouring money on it) and will go out of fashion soon (Am I right???). So I continued searching and the names that popped up are ExtJS (which was prevalent few year back) and AngularJS (heard it for the first time now). Spent some time searching both and both seems fine. So can you dashboard developers please help answer the following questions (as well as provide important input that I may be overlooking right now):

1. Cross-Compatibility: Need to develop desktop and mobile apps along with web page.
2. Prevalence: I will need to learn the technologies. Would prefer it they are popular and widely used
3. Dashboard features: Stuff like ability to go into bar graph and pie charts and stuff.
4. Ease of programming: Quality of Editors/IDE available, speed of programming etc.
5. Anything important that I am missing

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, I would go with Flex, because:

- You already know it
- Flex is a "compact" solution to your problem. Web frameworks imply you to learn a lot of new things. AngularJS is certainly cool but every web tek require you to master JS, CSS (I hate it), HTML, FireBug, PhoneGap, .... Web teks are a mess (IMHO !!!)
- Coming from C++, working with Flex is more comfortable than web tek. Dependency injection is cool but it's a new vision of the world. JS is really powerfull but is (also) a functional language and you will need to get a "lambda mind".

Two year ago I decided to try ExtJS to make a dashboard for an hospital. I gave up after some days when happened that finding and solving a simple bug in my simple app took me a full day! [I forgot a parenthesis. The page didn't open saying nothing at all).

I'm now trying to learn Flex because I need to produce a simple app for smartphone (I'm a newbie in that) that should be ready in a month and with Flex I think it's easier for me to succeed than with any web tech framework. I know that Flex future is obscure but I think it's too good to be killed even if Google's pressure is strong ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I searched for a few days and for cross compatibility, Flex still seems to be the best out there. Moreover the way things stands now, HTML 5 still seems to be just catching up. Considering that it was doing the same few years back, I must assume that it has not taken off in the big way we were promised it would.

Answer (score 2):

No-one seems to be keen to answer this question - I guess because it's a definitely going to be an opinon based answer. I'll give it a go...

To answer your first question - Flex is if not on the way out, at least on a low simmer. Adobe  Flash Builder 4.7 (the main Flex tooling IDE) has not been updated for well over a year now and I can't see any updates on the horizon.
Apache, who now own the codebase are doing a nice job with updates, but progress is slow.
One possible bright area is FlexJS, a compiler that outputs Javascript and HTML. It's still alpha at the moment, but it could be an option.

I've never developed in ExtJS, but it seems it's time has come and gone - it's still used, but it's definitely been superseded by Angular and other frameworks such as Knockout.

1. Cross-Compatibility - AngularJS works is almost all browsers from IE8 up and that includes most modern mobile browsers. People often use JQuery Mobile in combo with Angular and Bootstrap to get the functionality they need. Bootstrap is responsive, so if you lay out your UI correctly, it should work for all devices. 
   Flex is also cross compatible in the form of Adobe Air, but it's less easy to get it onto people's devices - they need to download the Air framework.
2. AngularJS is the number one framework by a huge margin at the moment - and it's still growing. Check out [this](http://www.google.com/trends/explore?hl=en-US#q=Angularjs,%20Backbone.js,%20Ember.js&date=today%2012-m&cmpt=q) graph from google trends. The combination of technologies includes Javascript, CSS, Grunt, Bower, Node.js and concepts such as dependency injection, MVC and responsive layout - all this stuff is useful for other projects. Once you master Angularjs, you'll be ready for a lot of other stuff. 
   Learning Flex seems to be a bit of a dead end at the moment - you'll notice the absence of any recent Flex blog posts. It's not cool right now, and it's just too uncertain if it's going to survive.
3. Using Angularjs and D3 for example is reasonably straightforward - a web search will show lots of examples here. Plus you can do basic drawing using svg elements directly in your HTML code. [Here's](http://alexandros.resin.io/angular-d3-svg/) a nice article on the subject.
4. Since Angular is a Javascript framework, there are many many options here - you could use SublimeText, Atom, PhpStorm or one of many other choices. As I said earlier, your choices are much more limited if you choose Flex.
5. Finally, don't forget that this is all just my opinion, but Angularjs is just really fun to develop in - binding is just so cool. So are directives. Dependency injection just rocks. I think you'll like it!

Sorry for the bias here, but I can't help it!!

Hopefully this writeup helps you a little. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will certainly look more deeply at AngularJS

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS is a good choice for complex web application (both desktop and mobile).

There is a project that implements Dashboard/Widgets functionality with AngularJS.

- GitHub source code https://github.com/DataTorrent/malhar-angular-dashboard
- live demo http://datatorrent.github.io/malhar-angular-dashboard/#/
- more advanced demo (charts, etc.) http://datatorrent.github.io/malhar-dashboard-webapp/#/

It targets desktop browsers so far but has a lot of features:

- Adding/removing widgets
- Widgets are instantiated dynamically (from corresponding directive or template)
- Widgets drag and drop (with jQuery UI Sortable)
- Horizontal and vertical widgets resize
- Fluid layout (widgets can have percentage-based width, or have width set in any other unit)
- Any directive or template can be a widget
- Connecting widgets to real-time data (WebSocket, REST, etc.)
- Changing widget data source dynamically (from widget options)
- Saving widgets state to local storage
- Multiple Dashboard Layouts